# I want to display the output as follows by writing sql query in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

In my schema i have the dept table data as follows

```
dept_id       dept_name   
  10             IT
  20             EE
  30             EC
  40             OP
```

I want to get the output as follows and i dont want to display column headdings dept_id and dept_name

```
 IT         EE           EC          OP      
 10         20           30          40
```

So, Please help me to get the result. This question asked by an Interviewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle 10g doesn't have the [`PIVOT`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) feature, so you'll need to use something like this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN dept_name = 'IT' THEN dept_id END) AS IT,
  MAX(CASE WHEN dept_name = 'EE' THEN dept_id END) AS EE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN dept_name = 'EC' THEN dept_id END) AS EC,
  MAX(CASE WHEN dept_name = 'OP' THEN dept_id END) AS OP
FROM dept
```